# How to include custom folder in config in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to add include path to custom folder in application.ini in Zend Framework?
I need access to some classes from custom folder.

Thx for answers.
Kamilos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
includePaths.customfolder = APPLICATION_PATH "/../customfolder"
```

Comment: it's not include my classes :(

Comment: Of course its not including class, this will only add to includepath path to folder where classes are stored. So for example if you have class.php in folder test/class.php you need to add in application.ini
includePaths.test= APPLICATION_PATH "/../test" this line and somewhere in code create class instance by $class = new Class()

Comment: Try to dump somewhere in bootstrap includepath by calling Zend_Debug::dump(get_include_path());

Comment: I resolve this in other way. Added to autoloaderNamespaces and now class can be found.
Dzięki za pomoc w każdym razie ;)

Comment: Maybe you have problem with class name, classes should be named in good convention. For example when class is inside of folder folder/folder1/Class.php the class name need to be Folder_Folder_1_Class - możesz zaakceptować odpowiedź jeżeli była pomocna xD

Comment: Hm, I think it was it :) pozdro

Answer (score 0):

structure your applications:

```
application
data
library
public
```

in application.ini

```
data_uploads = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/uploads"
```

in Bootstrap.php

```
public function _initDefines()
{
    define('DATA_UPLOADS', $this->getOption('data_uploads'));
}
```

now you can use `DATA_UPLOADS` define in your script php! ;)

---

### UPDATE

add this to application.ini

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Foo_"
```

in you libray add directory `Foo`! In this directory add your classes.
the filename class will be `Bar.php` and class name will be `Foo_Bar`!

Comment: this method will only define constant with path to folder but he will not be able to create classes stored in folder until adding DATA_UPLOADS to php include paths.

Comment: I did not realize he had to put them in classes! Sorry!